# Unable to import XSSFDateUtil package as part of POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

So yes, as the title suggests I'm unable to import DateUtil along with IndexedColors and XSSFColor. I've added all the relevant dependencies in my pom.xml file. No amount of googling would help me find the reason why this is happening.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I should've done this already. Poor form on my part. Nonetheless, I found out the issue, seems like I was referring to the incorrect packages in my code and eclipse wouldn't help me out for some reason.